# created data did not appear when testing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara, factory-bot

hye, I'm new to BDD testing and testing particularly. I'm using rspec, factory_girl_rails, selenium and capybara gem. I want to test for editing a data and save it like so :

```
  it "edit consultant" do
    # c = FactoryGirl.create(:consultant)
    c = Consultant.create(
      orgorcom: "xyz",
      year_id: 8,
      bidang: "IT & Networking",
      project: "E-Sw",
      professional_fee: "1000000",
      role: "Database Architect",
      user_id: 19,
      nopkj: "075899 "
      )
    visit "/consultants?year=#{Time.now.year}"
    string = "#consultant#{c.id}"
    page.find(string).click_link('Edit')
    fill_in "Organization / Company" , :with => c.orgorcom + "aaa"
    fill_in "Field", :with => c.bidang + "aaa"
    fill_in "Project" , :with => c.project + "aaa"
    fill_in "Role", :with => c.role + "aaa"
    fill_in "Professional fee", :with => c.professional_fee + 111
    click_button "Save"
    expect(page).to have_content "Data updated."
    sleep 10
    # c.destroy
    # find('a[href="/consultants/6144/edit?year=2013"]').click
  end
```

But the data I created did not appear & I get this message

```
  1) the consultation edit consultant
     Failure/Error: page.find(string).click_link('Edit')
     Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css "#consultant6157"
```

when I tried click on existing data like below, it passed.

```
page.find("#consultant6144").click_link('Edit')
```

I am able to print out the consultant id but still the record mysteriously did not appear before the test ends (which the db will rollback).

Comment: I don't see how that's related to FactoryGirl. You commented out the line where you make the call to FactoryGirl. You're simply creating an object with `.create` -- which is a Rails method, not a FactoryGirl method.

Comment: Are you paginating with more than a page of consultants for the current year, so that the most recently added consultant is off the page?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin nope, I did'nt paginate it, all data is visible.

Comment: @depa, (0.2ms)  RELEASE SAVEPOINT active_record_1 (0.6ms)  ROLLBACK, is this a FactoryGirl feature or what?

Comment: That has absolutely nothing to do with FactoryGirl. That's your test framework handling your test database for you.

Comment: Is it possible that your view was created by using some other id (e.g. `user.id`) rather than the `Consultant` id?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin, no not possible.

Comment: Have you looked at the `Consultant` id generated by the test (e.g. printed it out)?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin yep, the Consultant id is available. Im able to print it out

Answer (score 3):

This is a known issue if you're using Selenium for browser testing, with transactional fixtures configured in your `spec_helper`. Selenium will run in a different thread and with a different database connection than the one being used by Rspec to create your database objects inside transactions, therefore the Selenium thread won't be able to see them.

For these kind of specs, you will need to not use transactional fixtures and use something like [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) to create objects at the start of your specs and truncate/delete them afterwards.

Comment: I would like to use the available data on my development database. How is this possible? Different database connection didn't find my records even tough it is the same database? This sounds weird

Comment: You cannot and should not use your development database when testing. You have a test database for this.

Comment: But theres a lot of record dependencies for the app i am testing. I am trying Capybara.app_host = "http://thissystem.dev" but I'm getting Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2)

Comment: that would appear to be completely unrelated.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem doesn't seem related to FactoryGirl. The error message thrown by Capybara indicates that the object's id was properly concatenated into the string, but the corresponding CSS wasn't found in the page.

I would recommend you install the [launchy](https://github.com/copiousfreetime/launchy) gem by inserting this into your Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'launchy'
end
```

That will enable you to use the `save_and_open_page` method in your feature specs. Then insert this method right before the line that's provoking the error, like so:

```
# ...
save_and_open_page
page.find(string).click_link('Edit')
# ...
```

When `save_and_open_page` is called, your default browser will open at the same page. Then you can manually inspect the page's HTML and find out if it does, in fact, have the element you're looking for and, if it doesn't, why that happens.

Comment: I already got Firefox launched because i'm using selenium-webdriver and I wrote :js => true. In addition, I use sleep 10 second so that I have time to inspect before the test ends. I cannot find the record that I created.